# Server location with dotnet

Tags: .net-core

It is known that the cmd bellow if exist at the .csproj configuration file of my project:

```
<SpaProxyServerUrl>https://my.server.edu:44460</SpaProxyServerUrl>
```

will allow to call my app using the https://my.server.edu:44460.

For JavaScript there is a command that identifies the server where the app is running using:

`var host = window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.`host;

Is there a way to replace `https://my.server.edu:44460` with a dotnet cmd that will work as the previous JavaScript cmd so I do not need to rewrite the server identifier where my application will finally be deployed? i.e. the dotnet equivalent to

```
window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + ':44460'
```

I mean, at the end I want to have at the csproj configuration file something like:

```
<SpaProxyServerUrl>*window.location.protocol + "//" + window.location.host + ':44460'*</SpaProxyServerUrl>
```

I wonder also if the 44460 port value could be replaced by something more "generic"

Comment: Maybe this will help? [configuring-urls-with-kestrel-iis-and-iis-express-with-asp-net-core](https://andrewlock.net/configuring-urls-with-kestrel-iis-and-iis-express-with-asp-net-core/)

Comment: For what its worth, I would recommend you rewrite your question to say what you want to do, without the comparison to javascript methods. The JS you are showing seems to be completely different from anything in aspnetcore I have ever seen (is it express maybe?). I don't think there will exist anything that will simply be the "same thing" in net core. So we kind of need to know what you want to do on its own terms.

Comment: For instance, for a simple case, you can just edit your Launch profile in visual studio to set a base url.